# Search Gerrit changes by user access rights

Tags: search, gerrit, changeset

We have a Gerrit with quite a huge namespace and projects environment and every project has different rights in a matter of code-review or workflow voting and submitting. I sometimes create a set of batch changes accross several projects and then I need reviewers to check and submit. Is there any way how to filter the search results to show only the project which the user searching them can review or submit? Currently, I usually send the results just based on the topic, but this approach still shows all the changes to the reviewers even if they don't have rights to review. Any ideas on how to do or workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not exactly what you search for but maybe it can help:

You can use the clause visibleto:'USER-or-GROUP' to match only changes that are visible to 'USER' or to anyone who is a member of 'GROUP'.

More info in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit.cpqd.com.br/Documentation/user-search.html#_magical_operators).